# How big should a language vocabulary be?

Tags: language-agnostic

I started looking at the upcoming [C++0x specification](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C%2B%2B0x) today, and I started thinking on what is the right size for a language vocabulary. Initially, it struck me as very annoying that new keywords were introduced. At some rough level, the number of keywords in a language is, I think, an estimate of its complexity. That is, in the case of C++, adding new constructs would make it even harder to master the language. Thats one reason why the K&R book is so much smaller that the C++ equivalent.

After that, I thought about natural languages, whose vocabulary has been shown to grow linearly with time, regardless of the language (*). The only exception is, of course, [Newspeak](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newspeak), which says a lot. The vocabulary size in this case is related to the expressive power the language.

In programming languages, however, you can have very expressive languages with a small vocabulary size (ie, Lisp).

**So, to phrase this is a question, what, in your opinion, should a language vocabulary be - big and verbose or small and concise?**

Answer (score 5):

> How big should a language vocabulary
>   be?

**42.**

Answer (score 2):

I'm not convinced there is a real answer here.  Smaller is my preference but I can't quantify what small really is.  I'd prefer to see a lean set of operators with no redundancy in them.  This like is and as in C# annoy me.  They are too close in functionality.  If and Unless in many languages are the same way.  One can easily be constructed from the other.

I'm a big fan of Lisp which is quite minimal, but even there syntactic sugar exists (like ' instead of quote).

Comment: LISP minimal? It defines almost 1000 forms/functions!  R5RS Scheme has about 250 in contrast.

Comment: Lisp has 18 reserved words. http://www.scribd.com/doc/2150939/Reserved-Programming-Keywords-for-Assorted-Languages

Comment: It does however does not make it useful yet. If it's about reserved keywords, Scheme has none  :)

Comment: `return undef unless $var;` is better than `if( ! $var ){ return undef; }`

Comment: @Brad, I'm not convinced.  It's a little more readable, but if it makes the language more complex, is that worth the tradeoff?  It's no more expressive.

Answer (score 1):

I like small languages with clear ways to extend it.

(someone wiki this)

Answer (score 1):

Well, let's compare two languages - C++ and Smalltalk

- C++ - large number of reserved words, complex syntax, huge standards document
- Smalltalk - almost no reserved words, incredibly simple syntax, tiny standards document

Now look at the relative sucess of those languages. I think the conclusion is obvious - big is better.

Comment: Correlation does not imply causation.

Answer (score 1):

I would say as few as possible while maximizing functionality.  Exactly where to draw the line betwen consice and complexity is very subjective.

Answer (score 1):

As big as necessary, but no bigger?

Anyway, your question misses an obvious point. Languages can be hideously complex without using a lot of keywords. As an example, look at the `static`keyword in C++. It has what, 3, 4 different meanings? Does that make the language less complex than if they'd used 3 or 4 different keywords?

Comment: Of course you're right. That's why I said it's a rough equivalence, at best. There's also the issue of counting the standard library or just the core language, and many other issues...

Comment: Most languages overload meanings - the '*' symbol in C has at least three, for example.